# segmentation fault (core dumped) memoria dinamica C y NASM

Tags: c, memoria, nasm

estoy aprendiendo a usar memoria dinamica en C y NASM, tengo lo siguiente:

En C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void intDelete(int32_t* a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    intDelete((int*) malloc(8));
    return 0;
}
```

En NASM:

```
section .text
global intDelete
extern free
intDelete:
    call free
```

Al menos no estoy perdiendo memoria, pero no se a que se debe el segmentation fault, me podrian ayudar?

Comment: Me parece que le falta la instrucción para retornar (`ret`) a la función `intDelete`.

Comment: jajaja era eso! gracias